# How to hide column titles of a Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, sitepages, classic-experience

I have made a SharePoint page with a list on it and I have set the style of the list to blocks. As you can see below.

But how can I hide the column titles?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below settings in list view:

[image]

If this is not working for you then add below code to your SharePoint page using Script Editor or Content Editor web part:

```
function hideColumnHeaders(){
    // hide list column headers
    document.querySelector("table[summary^='TESTLIJSTPK'] tbody tr").style.display = "none";
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideColumnHeaders");
```

OR replace code inside function with:

```
document.querySelector("table[summary^='TESTLIJSTPK'] tbody tr:first-child").style.display = "none";
```

Where `TESTLIJSTPK` is name of your list.

**Output**: No column headers/titles at the top

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings → Style → View style and edited to "No labels"