# How to hide the column titles of all the lists on a Sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, sitepages, classic-experience

Yesterday I have asked [how to hide the titles of the columns of a list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293322/how-to-hide-column-titles-of-a-sharepoint-list) on a SharePoint page.

But is it also possible to hide the column titles of multiple lists on a page?

Comment: All lists have the same boxed style or different styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code in script editor or content editor web part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function hideAllListsColumnHeaders(){
        var allListTables = document.querySelectorAll("table.ms-listviewtable");

        for(var i = 0; i < allListTables.length; i++) {
            var tbodyElement = allListTables[i].firstChild;
            var trElement = tbodyElement.firstChild;
            trElement.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideAllListsColumnHeaders");

</script>
```

1. Add content editor web part on your page.
2. Click on **click here to add new content**

   [image]
3. Click **Edit Source** under **FORMAT TEXT** tab

   [image]
4. Paste above code in **HTML Source** dialog opened
5. Click **OK**
6. Click **Stop Editing** under **PAGE** tab in ribbon

Comment: Where do i have to paste the code in a content editor web part?

Comment: All lists have the same boxed style

Comment: Check updated answer & steps to add code.

Comment: Thanks for the help